# ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 1:0 in Installing Laravel vue auth command

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, webpack

working in Laravel App and my node version is 16 and working with Laravel 9 and install `php artisan ui vue --auth`.my web.pack.js is like this

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

package.json is

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.6.3",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.37",
        "vue-loader": "^16.2.0"
    }
}
```

but when I try to run `npm run dev` it is encounting following error msgs and laravel mix error

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div class="container">
|         <div class="row justify-content-center">

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

how could I fix this problem

Comment: mabe also show your app.js and the component definition? This usualy contains important info as well

Comment: I think you need to add ` .vue()` in your  webpack config like `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue().postCss...`
read [here](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade#api-for-javascript-frameworks)

Comment: but Id rather switch to vite  and stop using webpack

Comment: `[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:`

Answer (score 0):

use below lines in `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix"); 
const path = require("path");
```

then modify your code to this.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ])
    .vue({
        version: 3
    })
    .webpackConfig({
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: "vue-loader",
            }, ],
        },
    });
;
```

Comment: did above changes now cmd display this `Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

        Running: npm install vue-loader@^16.2.0 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps

        Finished. Please run Mix again.`

Comment: run above command run `npm run dev` now got following error msg `[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:`